# aws sqs message queue AWSCredentials class not found error

Tags: java, maven, amazon-sqs

Using maven for build. Testing Amazon SQS connectivity.  Java code gets compiled but when I ran it receiving an AWSCredentials Class not found error.     I have imported AmazonSQS  in the java code. Not sure why it's giving me an error.

```
java -cp "./target/queue-service-1.0.0.jar"  com.example.TestSqsQueueService
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentials
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials
```

Have the below configuration in pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.23</version>
</dependency>
```

Have the below Java code in the main function and import the below files
package com.example;

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.*;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.*;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.*;

public class TestSqsExample {

public static void main(String args[]) {
       BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials("XXXXXXXXX",  "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
     AmazonSQSClient s3Client = new AmazonSQSClient(awsCreds);

    System.out.println("hello world");

}
}
```

Comment: can anyone helpme about this query

Comment: Does your jar contain the dependencies within it (jar-with-dependencies)?